# Leaflet Custom TileLayer - how to convert real-world coords to my map where centre is 0,0

Tags: leaflet, convert, latitude-longitude

I have a working leaflet map which utilizes a single **TileLayer** to display my custom map tiles.

It's a cartoon style map of a real location and everything is to scale. In fact you could place a google satelite map over the top of it and everything would line up perfectly.

I want to be able to plot real life lat/lon coords on my cartoon map.

The problem is, I've discovered it adopts it's own scale and coordinate system where the centre is 0,0.

I'm wondering if there's the possibility to do one of the following:

**a)** Specify in leaflet what the real life centrepoint and bounds of my map are?

OR

**b)** From marrying up various coordinates e.g: centrepoint and bounds of my cartoon map to the real life equivalents, devise some kind of formula to convert between the two.

I've actually spent some time on approach (b) but not been successful.
I thought I could do something along the following lines:

```
    latlngToXY: function(lat, lng) {

        // 0,0 on the cartoon map, marries up to these coords
        var mapCentre = {
           lat: -23.9076758,
           lng: 153.3127296
        };

        // Subtract mapCentre to get offset from 0
        var x = lat-mapCentre.lat;
        var y = lng-mapCentre.lng;

        // Get the scale multiplier, calculated from (lat-mapCentre.lat) divided by an already known cartoon map lat
        var scaleRatio = -30652.911561212319766;

        x = x*scaleRatio;
        y = y*scaleRatio;

        return [x,y];
  }
```

It worked fine for one of my coords (unsurprisingly the one I calculated the scaleRatio from), but is wildly inaccurate for anything else.

Maybe someone could point out what I'm missing or perhaps indicate if it's even going to be possible.

Comment: Can you please post more detailed example of your map setup, in example on jsfiddle, codepen or other platform?

Comment: Sounds related to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266645/how-the-pointing-path-towards-the-png-is-determined-during-basemap-display-using

Comment: This tutorial on non-geographical maps might help you: http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html